# jQuery animation triggers callback twice when run

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I'm animating a scroll to effect using jQuery, after the animation ends, I trigger an effect, for some reason the effect is triggered twice, how can I prevent it from happening?

```
$('.something').on('click', function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('footer').offset().top
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 1500,
                complete: function() {
                    $('.foo').toggleClass('active');
                    $('.bar').slideToggle();    
                }
            });                
            return false;
        });
```

The slideToggle effect seems to be triggered twice.
I have it animate on html & body because animate from 'body' doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're triggering two animations (on html and body) the complete callback should be called twice.

You might want to on trigger the animation on html only if it's required

```
var animateOn = isIE8 ? 'html' : 'body';
$(animateOn).animate();
```